# why does my main activity show's first than my splash screen

Tags: java, android

> this the first part of the code with the splash screen code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 1000;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "example.txt";
    EditText mEditText;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(homeIntent);
                    finish();

            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

> the first thing that comes out after i run the app is the main activity and not the splash screen

Comment: check your menifest file its should have two launcher activity

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify your activity Actions by using Intent Filter ,
Intent Filters specifies the types of intents that an activity, service, or broadcast receiver can respond to. An intent filter declares the capabilities of its parent component — what an activity or service can do and what types of broadcasts a receiver can handle. It opens the component to receiving intents of the advertised type, while filtering out those that are not meaningful for the component.

As in For your Case, You have to specify that MainActivity/SplashActivity should be on Launcher Mode(Launcher mode is an instruction for Android OS which specifies how the activity should be launched), you have to use Intent filter and specify Activity Actions ,

*Must go through this Article [App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro)

Add this in your Manifest file within `<Application>` Tag

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: `Add this in your Manifest file within <Application> Tag` you would get a lot more upvotes if you _explained_ your answers. you need to actually make people understand why an answer works

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thanks Bro, a great suggestion. Will follow this in my next answers :)

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest file, **SplashActivity** must be set as Launcher activity. Check the name of the Splash screen activity file in your project.

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your manifest? Launch Activity should be Splash Activity.

Which Activity you want the application to start with, you need to add IntentFilter in that Activity in the Manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="SplashActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but it has helped me pinpoint another issue on my end, given the solutions above. In the Android Studio emulator, you want to `run configurations` on app and not MainActivity since that launches you into the main activity if you are running with the run button. Else, launching the app on the phone screen works.